# Prevent from visual studio to load symbols from specific folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2017, symbols

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and I'm developing WPF application that load dlls from other users by using:

```
Assembly.LoadFile(filePath);
```

After every load, the visual studio try to load the symbols from these dlls and sometimes it take a lot of time.

I have found several solutions that didn't work for me:

1. Enable "Just My Code" - didn't work
2. Specify excluded modules - didn't work because I use cache mechanism that gives every time the dlls different file name, so I can't specify the actual file name.
3. `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH` variable is not defined.

Is there a way to load the dlls without the symbols? Or prevent from visual studio to load symbols from specific folder (All the dlls are in specific folder)?

**Update:**

I tried also:

4. Delete All Breakpoints - didn't work
5. Uncheck all non-local sources for Symbol file (.pdb) locations e.g. Microsoft Symbol - didn't work
6. Load only specified modules - Could work but I prefer not to maintain this list because I use many projects and I open the solution from different locations. Maybe there is a way to load only .pdb files from the solution?

Comment: You have tried "Specify excluded modules". Did you also try "Load only specified modules" from the Debug -> Options -> Symbols setting?

Comment: Have you tried to Uncheck all non-local sources for Symbol file (.pdb) locations
e.g. Microsoft Symbol Servers   Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols

Comment: 1. Load only specified modules - Could work but I prefer not to maintain this list because I use many projects and I open the solution from different locations. Maybe there is a way to load only module from the solution?

2. I tried to uncheck all non-local sources.

Comment: Have you tried used method "Assembly.LoadFrom(filepath)"?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/best-practices-for-assembly-loading

Comment: @FletchZhou-MSFT I tried and I got the same behavior. The symbol was loaded.

Comment: @itaiy, As far as I know, some symbols are loaded automatically. There is no way to turn this behavior off. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/14fb87ee-3da0-42f8-8461-b07d93e13691/how-to-avoid-loading-symbols?forum=vsdebug